# Deploying Pyramid app: Nginx + Pserve

Tags: nginx, pyramid, digital-ocean

I've been following [this recipe](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html) in the Pyramid Cookbook to try and deploy my app on DigitalOcean. It seems to work, I get the message `Entering daemon mode` just like I did when running on my local machine.

I've also added my domain name and set up my nameservers to point to DigitalOcean.

When I try to access my site at [wisderm.com](http://wisderm.com) though, it doesn't load. I'm completely lost at this point -- What am I doing wrong?

This is how my files are structured:

```
home/
  |----env/ # virtualenv
  |----MyApp/
        |
        |----production.ini
        |----requirements.txt
        |----myapp.sql
        |----myapp.psql
        |----MyProject
              |
              |----scripts/
              |----static/
              |----templates/
              |----__init__.py
              |----views.py
              |----models.py
```

This is my app.conf:

```
upstream myapp-site {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}

server {

    server_name  wisderm.com;

    access_log  /home/MyApp/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   60s;
        proxy_send_timeout      90s;
        proxy_read_timeout      90s;
        proxy_buffering         off;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_pass http://myapp-site;
        proxy_redirect          off;
    }

    location /static {
      root                    /home/MyApp;
      expires                 30d;
      add_header              Cache-Control public;
      access_log              off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the Nginx log (`/var/log/nginx/...`)? Is there anything in your application log (`/home/myapp/access.log`)? Why it is `/home/myapp` in one place and `/home/MyApp` in another? Are you aware the closing `}` seems to be missing in the `location /static {` section?

Comment: Also, I think if your config was working it would expose all your website's source code at `/static/`. I think the directive should be `root    /home/MyApp/MyProject/static`

Comment: I checked out the error logs using tail /var/log/nginx/error.log, and there are plenty of these errors: 
 
``2014/04/22 01:24:18 [error] 25568#0: *11 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 220.255.2.78, server: wisderm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "wisderm.com"`` 
 
``2014/04/22 02:12:13 [error] 25792#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 220.255.2.78, server: wisderm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "wisderm.com"``

Comment: The MyApp vs myapp was a typo, I've corrected it. I don't see any missing ``}``, my indentation was slightly off though so I've corrected that too. As for the root directory, in the Pyramid cookbook link it says that its odd that the root doesn't point to the static directory, but it works because Nginx will append the actual URL to the specified path. But perhaps it should be ``/home/MyApp/MyProject``?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx after adding `app.conf`? Is it in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`? Can you confirm your main nginx config has a directive to include everything in the dir where your config is located?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted nginx. There are these lines in the ``http {}`` of nginx.conf: ``include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;``
 ``include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51174/discussion-between-sergey-and-bard)